# JPA Persistence: Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory - Error creating DatabaseInformation for schema migration

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to access an Oracle XE 11g Database (currently running under docker but it is working fine - I can connect from SQLDeveloper remotely) with JPA on a Wildfly 10.

I setup my persistence.xml unit like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="oracle">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.77.132:49161:xe" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="lunchapp" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="lunchapp" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="FLUSH_AUTO" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

When I start the deployment I get the following error:

```
[2016-07-07 08:41:06,969] Artifact lunchtool:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2016-07-07 08:41:06,970] Artifact lunchtool:war exploded: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.lunchtool#oracle" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.lunchtool#oracle: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: oracle] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: oracle] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error creating DatabaseInformation for schema migration
    Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Tabelle \"ALL_SEQUENCES\" nicht gefunden
Table \"ALL_SEQUENCES\" not found; SQL statement:
 select sequence_name from all_sequences  union select synonym_name   from all_synonyms us, all_sequences asq  where asq.sequence_name = us.table_name    and asq.sequence_owner = us.table_owner [42102-173]"}}
```

Anyhow - the shown sql statement can be executed via sqldeveloper.
IntelliJ also detected the Datasource and when I test the connection it is working fine.

I have the ojdbc6.jar and it is also deployed correctly to wildfly (ie WEB-INF/lib in the exploded deployment on wildfly).

Now I am at a point where I have no idea what is wrong or how I can investigate what I am doing wrong.

Any advice welcome :-)

Thank you!

Comment: Look here: `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException`. Looks like at one Point is h2db configured

Comment: `ALL_SEQUENCES not foud` - sounds like the user has no access to `ALL_SEQUENCES` dictionary view. Could you connect to the database as `lunchapp` user in SQL-Developer or SQLPlus and run a query: `SELECT * FROM ALL_SEQUENCES` to check whether this view is visible to the user ?

Comment: @kordirko yes I can see the data when executing the statement as lunchapp user in sqldeveloper.

Comment: @Jens that is interesting - I made a complete workspace search but found no occurence of h2 (and I also did not configure anything with h2). I can only see some org.h2.* classes inside some hibernate compile time libraries but those are not part of the deployment